# Special overload for pointer types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, default-template-argument

Consider the following snippet:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct remove_pointer
{
};

template <class T>
struct remove_pointer<T*>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
T
clone(const T& v)
{
    return v;
}


template <typename T, typename U = typename remove_pointer<T>::type>
T
clone(const U& v)
{
    return new U(v);
}


int main() 
{
    auto foo = clone<double>(42.0);
    return 0;
}
```

This code generates compilation errors:

```
 In function 'int main()':
30:34: error: call of overloaded 'clone(double)' is ambiguous
30:34: note: candidates are:
14:1: note: T clone(const T&) [with T = double]
22:1: note: T clone(const U&) [with T = double; U = double]
```

Why is the compiler deriving `T=double, U=double` in line 22? I thought it only should pass if `T` is a pointer type.

Comment: default template is only used when not provided or deduced. it is deduced here.

Comment: Understood! Can can I make the specialised overload only pass if T is a pointer?

Comment: you want to be able to have `clone<double*>(42.0)`. but what for `double* p = /*..*/; clone<double*>(p)`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? If `clone` gets a `T*` it should return a `T` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 For the code "as written" it would be the other way around (the second `clone` takes the non-pointer type and returns the pointer type, both in signature and body).

Comment: @MaxLanghof well, I have problems to take the code literally, because I am not sure if thats what OP initially aimed for

Comment: What should `clone` do when given an `int**`?

Comment: The code is a very reduced snippet of a library for binding c++ code to Dart FFI. I know the code looks weird standalone because I reduced it the core issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler deduced `U=double` and didn't use your default argument at all. I think that you can try to have two different overloads for your `clone` function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30556345/4165552).

Your example might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T
clone(const T& v, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value >::type* = 0)
{
    std::cout << "non ptr clone" << std::endl;
    return v;
}

template <typename T>
T
clone(const T v, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value >::type* = 0)
{
    std::cout << "ptr clone" << std::endl;
    using noptrT = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*v)>::type;
    return new noptrT(*v);
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = clone<double>(42.0);
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    double* ptr = new double(69.69);
    auto bar = clone<double*>(ptr);
    std::cout << *bar << std::endl;
    delete ptr;
    delete bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this solution also allows you to pass a function pointer

```
void fun() {}
...
clone<void(*)()>(fun);
```

which will result in compilation error (new cannot be applied to function type).

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the compiler deriving T=double, U=double in line 22? I thought it only should pass if T is a pointer type.

Because template arguments are deduced based on passed non-template arguments. You passed a double literal into an argument of type `const U&`, so `U` was deduced to be `double`. The default of the template argument is not used if the argument is deduced.

And the problem is that both the single template argument, as well as the two template argument overloads can be called with the same argument list, so the compiler doesn't know which overload you intended to call.

Answer (score 1):

```
clone<double>(42.0);
```

could either mean

- "instantiate the first `clone` with the explicit template argument `double`", or
- "instantiate the second `clone` with the first argument explicitly given as `double` and the second one deduced from `42.0` being passed in place of `const U& v`". The default value you provide is ignored, `U` is deduced from matching `double` to `const U&`.

The compiler can't decide which one you meant, so you get an error. Maybe you intended to use SFINAE to specialize the function template. But specializing function templates is strongly discouraged (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

One way to express what you want would be `if constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/_YGXGc

But the semantics of this function are still quite weird. Sometimes the function returns a heap-allocated pointer and sometimes it returns a value. The user has to pass the target type (in both cases or just one?). This will be really confusing at the call site.